# HttpRequest Node.js "Cannot set property 'UNSENT' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, httprequest

I have a problem, when I try to run a simple http request I always get an error message.

*Cannot set property 'UNSENT' of undefined*

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

XMLHttpRequest('https://example.firebaseio.com/.json',
   function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
       console.log(body);        
     }
   }
);
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the standard built-in NodeJS methods:

This code:

```
var http = require('http');
http.get('http://nodejs.org/dist/index.json', (res) => {
  const statusCode = res.statusCode;
  const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

  let error;
  if (statusCode !== 200) {
    error = new Error(`Request Failed.\n` +
                      `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
  } else if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
    error = new Error(`Invalid content-type.\n` +
                      `Expected application/json but received ${contentType}`);
  }
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    // consume response data to free up memory
    res.resume();
    return;
  }

  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  let rawData = '';
  res.on('data', (chunk) => rawData += chunk);
  res.on('end', () => {
    try {
      let parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
      console.log(parsedData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  });
}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
});
```

is taken from [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```js
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
    req.open('GET',url)

    req.onload = function(){
    if(req.status==200){
     console.log(req.responseText)
        }

    else{
     console.log(req.statusText)
       }
    }

    req.onerror = function()
    {
    console.log('Network Error')
    }

    req.send()
    })
```